# How to get sqlite file name in SQLAlchemy engine connect event

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy, sqlcipher

I am using following code to set secret for sqlcipher version of sqlite. It has to be the first command sent to database. Therefore I can't use `PRAGMA database_list;` to get the filename, because I don't know if this sqlite file is encrypted or not.

I need to distinguish between sqlite files that are encrypted by filename, or by something I could pass when I am creating engine. In other words I need to know beforehand if file is supposed to be encrypted to know if I have to send the `PRAGMA key`.

I tried to find some clue in `dbapi_connection` and `connection_record` objects that would help me to identify which file I am dealing with, but no luck.

```
@event.listens_for(Engine, "connect")
def set_sqlite_pragma(dbapi_connection, connection_record):
    from sqlite3 import Connection as sqliteConnection
    if isinstance(dbapi_connection,sqliteConnection):
        cursor = dbapi_connection.cursor()
        query  = "PRAGMA key='" + CIPHERSECRET + "'"
        cursor.execute(query)
        cursor.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

The first 16 bytes of a SQLCipher database file are a random salt, which differs from the default in SQLite which is `SQLite format 3\000`.  You could attempt to read the the first 16 bytes and look for the SQLite constant and make your decision based on that value.

Comment: Seems that my question is not clear. I am asking how to find out in this event handler which file is being used. Once I know the file, I know if its encrypted or not. Or I could test it as you suggested, but I don't know the file name.